# At what point is a question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I recently asked [The devil virus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20674/the-devil-virus?noredirect=1#comment65041_20674), which got put on hold for being too broad. I narrowed the question down and gave a hint, and now people are saying it's a duplicate of [James Bond : No Access](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13240/james-bond-no-access). I agree that it's quite similar and that the answer relies on the same kind of joke, but can't we say the same about [the 27 variations of Knights and Knaves](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=knights%20%26%20knaves%20is%3Aquestion) we got? or the [7 variations of the Poisoned Wine detection puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=poison%20bottle%20is:question)? or the 265 [word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) questions that are all based on wordsmithing? They're duplicates in that they both rely on the same functionality of Linux, but the way the function is called is different.

When can we consider 2 questions duplicates? If my question really is a duplicate, I have no problems with it being closed because of community consensus that it's duplicate, but I'm fairly sure there are other questions with similar answers out there that are still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the user who posted the devil virus puzzle made it clear with the first provided hint that the question was a rehash/dupe of the james bond riddle. 007/666 = permissions gag.